# Определение нативных double констант

Tags: c#

Увидел такие строки в метаданных System:

```
public const Double NaN = 0D / 0D;
public const Double NegativeInfinity = -1D / 0D;
public const Double PositiveInfinity = 1D / 0D;
```

И у меня вопрос, почему 0/0 не дает исключение, чем NaN будет отличаться от 0?

Аналогично и с инфинити.

Comment: потому что `double` реализует стандарт [IEEE](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008), соответсвуя которому числа с плавающей точкой должны иметь NaN, -∞ и +∞

Comment: `NaN` - это отнюдь не `0`, это `Not a Number`, неопределённость, появляющаяся при делении `0` на `0`.

Comment: Деление на 0 дает исключение при делении целых чисел, например int/int

Comment: Всем спасибо за ответы!